# i am trying to create a simple program that will give me 23% of 2500000 I cannot get this to work no matter what i change. I am using notepad++

Tags: javascript

```
var TotalSales = $2, 500, 000;
var Profit = (TotalSales * 23 / 100);

console.log {
    "annual profit:" + math.floor {
        Profit
    };
```

Comment: I seriously doubt `$2, 500, 000` is a valid number in Javascript.

Comment: Also, unless this is a new feature, curly brackets aren't a vid replacement for normal parentheses in the call to `console.log`.

Comment: This must be a troll, I refuse to believe he's serious.

Comment: @Azamantes The thought crossed my mind. This code actually gets more bizarre the more I look at it, so you may be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, you can't write a number with either

- multiple `,` (or any, for that matter)
- a unit like $

You can read more about numbers in Javascript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)

Also, when you define a function, you use `{`, but when you *call* a function, like `console.log()` you use `(`. You can learn more about functions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

So the  code needs to look like this:

```js
 var TotalSales = 2500000;
    var Profit = (TotalSales * (23 / 100));
    
    console.log("annual profit: $" + Math.floor(Profit));
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use '$' and ',' while assigning a value to variable

```
<script>
    var TotalSales = 2500000; 
    var Profit = (TotalSales * 23 / 100);
    console.log ("annual profit:" + Profit);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

java code :

```
    double TotalSales = 2500000;
    double profit = (TotalSales * 23 / 100);
    int floorProfit = (int) Math.round(profit);
    System.out.println("annual profit: "+floorProfit);
```

Comment: this question has also  java tag that time , but perhaps he edited that :-)

Comment: @NickanB ah, gotcha :)